# My app icon does not appear in the emulator home screen

Tags: android

I want specific ordered reasons why my app icon does not appear, I can run it on the emulator yet and I need to know what's wrong with my app? I'm a beginner my code is so simple, though I can't find why is this happening.

Here is my manifest:

```
         <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
           <activity
               android:name=".Splash"
               android:label="@string/app_name" >
             <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.launcher" />
             </intent-filter>
          </activity>
          <activity
             android:name=".MyActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name">
                  <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="com.example.hp.app2.MyActivity" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                 </intent-filter>
          </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: Is the app icon invisible? Or are you trying to use a custom icon and you still see the default?

Comment: um not trying to use any custom icon , simply when i run the emulator i cant find my app icon on the emulator home screen

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.launcher" />
```

it must be

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: yeah but still cant see the icon , is ther anything else i should consider ?

Comment: DO you need `intent-filter` for `.MyActivity`? if not, remove it.

Comment: i thought it should be there ,, and should be launcher so when i run the app the thread works